# Custom validation in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, django-validation

I have a very simple Django app in order to record the lectures given my colleagues.Since it is quite elementary,I am using the Django admin itself. Here is my models.py:

```
#models.py
from django.db import models

class Lecture(models.Model):
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    speaker = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
```

I need to ensure that nobody enters the start date after the end date in the admin forms,so I read the django docs for custom validation in the admin and implemented the following in my admin.py:

```
#admin.py
from models import Lecture
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms


class LectureForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Lecture

        def clean(self):
            start_date = self.cleaned_data.get('start_date')
            end_date = self.cleaned_data.get('end_date')
            if start_date > end_date:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Dates are incorrect")
        return self.cleaned_data


class LectureAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = LectureForm
    list_display = ('topic', 'speaker', 'start_date', 'end_date')

admin.site.register(Lecture, LectureAdmin)
```

However,this has no effect whatsoever on my admin and I am able to save lectures where start_date is after end_date as seen in the image:[image]

What am I doing wrong ??

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You have an indentation issue. Your `clean` method is indented within the form's Meta class. Move it back one level. Also, ensure that the `return` statement is indented within the method.

Comment: that worked !!..and I almost spent 2 hours re reading the docs to get a fix for it !!..I had one more doubt..the validation error was thrown up only when i created a new entry.For the existing ones,they continued to be there..I am assuming that the clean() method is called only when a model is saved.How do i ensure that it is called every time the page loads ?

Comment: @Amistad  The `clean` method is called only when the form is submitted, not "when the model is saved" (if that's what you want you're looking for model's validation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects)... Which will still not validate your model instances "every time the page loads", but why would you want such a "feature" anyway ?

Comment: hmm..now that I think of it,all my changes to the model happen only via the admin through the form..so a validation check there should suffice..thanks..

Comment: @bruno..when i use start_date and end_date in the list editable in the change list view and try changing the dates there,the form validation does not kick in..How do i ensure that form validation is performed while performing changes via the list editable option ??

Comment: You can define the [`get_changelist_form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_changelist_form) method to return a custom form to use there.

Comment: Fixed link for @brunodesthuilliers comment:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

Comment: Just in case it can help other people: Note that it's important to import "from django.forms import ValidationError" NOT "from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError"

Answer (score 73):

Usually you just want to define a clean() method on the model itself.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Lecture(models.Model):
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    speaker = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()

    def clean(self):
        if self.start_date > self.end_date::
            raise ValidationError("Dates are incorrect")
```

Something like that will work in the django admin without any need to create a form class.

Comment: In my case although error is raised, object is still able to be saved even after error raised

Comment: Keep in mind that a model's `clean()` method isn't called automatically with `save()`. This works in the Admin page because its forms call the `clean()` method for you. You'll still need to call `clean()` before `save()` elsewhere. From the docs: ["Note, however, that like Model.full_clean(), a model’s clean() method is not invoked when you call your model’s save() method."](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean)

Comment: Worth to note that changing the error raised by `ValidationError({"field_name": "Dates are incorrect"})`, the message will be displayed along the field named "field_name". Also adding more `"field": "message error .."` pairs to the dict will allow to add more errors specific to each field.

Answer (score 0):

```
def clean(self): 
   if self.database_name != '111':
      raise ValidationError("You can use only letters ,numbers and 
      underscores.")
```

This clean method works perfect for me in django admin